# PHP Mod Rewrite Sitemap Software Not Working

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, sitemap

I was looking to make the URLs on my site a bit more SEO friendly after reading a few sites about it. Basically I wanted old URLs that looked like

```
/showarticle.php?articleid=1
/showstory.php?storyid=1
```

to instead go to these urls:

```
/article/1/article-headline
/news/1/news-headline
```

I got this working by using the following mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /showarticle.php?articleid=$1 [PT] [L]
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$ /showstory.php?storyid=$1 [PT] [L]
```

However, since implementing those sitemap software and sites don't seem to be working properly. phpsitemapNG finds just 1 page, and XML-sitemaps.com finds some but not all. On the other end of the scale though, GSiteCrawler and AuditMyPC find more than there are by replacing the headline part of the url with other stuff such as:

```
/news/1/contact.php
/news/1/virtualnetwork.php
/news/1/compare.php
```

These are all pages on my site but not in the news or article section and there's no links to any of these pages in the form that they're picking them up. Is this something to do with my rewrite rule or just something that sitemap generators do in general?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^/article/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/(.*)/?$ showarticle.php?articleid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** The OP originally added this to their question. I have moved it to an answer to be in line with site guidelines.

---

Just a quick note to say that this issue has been sorted out. I just had to use absolute URLs to stop this from happening.